# How to add multiple editor configs in EXTJS Grid component column?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to add more than one editor config for a grid column.

For example, I want to see textbox for first cell and combo box for second cell.

Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.
Deepak

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use two..Just use xtype for grid columns...
e.g;

```
{
header:'textfield column',
editor:{
xtype:'textfield',
allowBlank:false
}
},
{
header:'combo column',
editor:{
xtype:'combo',
}
}
```

And ofcourse you need to declare the plugin in the grid config,like...

```
plugins: [
          Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
          })
      ]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i do not want this i want multiple edit controls under the same column.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the `getEditor` function in your `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` plugin to allow for using a different editor based on the data in the record.  Look at the answer in this post, it has a good example of how to do this: [ExtJS 4, Different rows fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572354/extjs-4-different-rows-fields)